# Synchronize three Threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following program (made up example!):

```
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<iostream>

class MultiClass {
    public:
        void Run() {
            std::thread t1(&MultiClass::Calc, this);
            std::thread t2(&MultiClass::Calc, this);
            std::thread t3(&MultiClass::Calc, this);
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        }
    private:
        void Calc() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    MultiClass m;
    m.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

What I need is to sync the loop iterations the following way and I cant come up with a solution (I've been fiddling for about an hour now using mutexes but cant find THE combination):
`t1` and `t2` shall do one loop iteration, then `t3` shall do one iteration, then again `t1` and `t2` shall do one, then `t3` shall do one.

So you see, I need `t1` and `t2` to do things simultaneously and after one iteration, `t3` shall do one iteration on its own.

Can you point your finger on how I would be able to achieve that? Like I said, ive been trying this with mutexes and cant come up with a solution.

Comment: Why do you want to create 3threads, when at most 2 are allowed to run in parallel?

Comment: 1. The explanation states that only 2 Threads run in parallel, 2. It depends on your hardware. On a modern CPU there can run more that two threads in parallel (e.g. quadcore of dualcore with HT)

Comment: In your example you are creating 3 Thread objects of which only 2 are allowed to logically run in parallel. This usually means that you loose performance. I was asking why that is the case, because there are different possibilities to achieve what you want, but depending on the reason for your program structure, one might be preferable to another.

Comment: If you want to parallelize your code for performance reasons, my answer would be: Use a parallel programming library, that does all of the scheduling for you, so you don't have to worry about how many cores your enduser machine has.

Comment: Missunderstood you comment. Sorry. It has a reason why it must be done this way in my case. Would be a long case to explain... sorry again for the missunderstanding!

Comment: Have you considered using `promise` and `future` or `async`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this by hand with the given thread structure, you could use something like this*:

```
class SyncObj {
    mutex mux;
    condition_variable cv;  
    bool completed[2]{ false,false };

public:
    void signalCompetionT1T2(int id) {
        lock_guard<mutex> ul(mux);
        completed[id] = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
    void signalCompetionT3() {
        lock_guard<mutex> ul(mux);
        completed[0] = false;
        completed[1] = false;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
    void waitForCompetionT1T2() {
        unique_lock<mutex> ul(mux);             
        cv.wait(ul, [&]() {return completed[0] && completed[1]; });         
    }
    void waitForCompetionT3(int id) {
        unique_lock<mutex> ul(mux);         
        cv.wait(ul, [&]() {return !completed[id]; });           
    }       
};

class MultiClass {
public:
    void Run() {
        std::thread t1(&MultiClass::Calc1, this);
        std::thread t2(&MultiClass::Calc2, this);
        std::thread t3(&MultiClass::Calc3, this);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
private:
    SyncObj obj;
    void Calc1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            obj.waitForCompetionT3(0);
            std::cout << "T1:" << i << std::endl;
            obj.signalCompetionT1T2(0);
        }           
    }
    void Calc2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            obj.waitForCompetionT3(1);
            std::cout << "T2:" << i << std::endl;
            obj.signalCompetionT1T2(1);
        }
    }
    void Calc3() {      
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            obj.waitForCompetionT1T2();
            std::cout << "T3:" << i << std::endl;
            obj.signalCompetionT3();
        }       
    }
};
```

However, this is only a reasonable approach, if each iteration is computational expensive, such that you can ignore the synchronization overhead. If that is not the case you should probably better have a look at a proper parallel programming library like intel's tbb or microsofts ppl.

*)NOTE: This code is untested and unoptimized. I just wrote it to show what the general structure could look like

Comment: This is just awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use two condition variables, here is a sketch..

thread 1 & 2 wait on condition variable `segment_1`:

```
std::condition_variable segment_1;
```

thread 3 waits on condition variable `segment_2`;

```
std::condition_variable segment_2;
```

threads 1 & 2 should `wait()` on `segment_1`, and thread 3 should `wait()` on `segment_2`. To kick off threads 1 & 2, call `notify_all()` on `segment_1`, and once they complete, call `notify_one()` on `segment_2` to kick off thread 3. You may want to use some controlling thread to control the sequence unless you can chain (i.e. once 1 & 2 complete, the last one to complete calls notify for thread 3 and so on..)

This is not perfect (see lost wakeups)

Comment: I agree with such an approach, for this to work each thread should have its own thread ID that it can use to check what it should do: if((myId == 1) || (myId == 2)) { wait(segment_1); } else { wait(segment_2); }

Comment: In my main program threads have an ID, forgot to mention that! Thanks for this approach!