Synchronize three Threads in C++ one after the other
This is in continuation to this really nice one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33500554/22598822. That post was for the sequence (t1 & t2) --> t3. Let's say I have a program running, and there are three threads that I want to keep in an inner execution sequence t1 --> t2 --> t3 (other threads may or may not be running simultaneously on the system). How can it be done?
I took the code from the reference above and tried to rework it for this goal, though unsuccessfully. My implementation is incorrect, I'm putting it here for a minimal reproducible example and maybe a possible starting point.
Header.h:
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<iostream>
#include <condition_variable>

MultiClass.h
#include "Header.h"
#include "SynchObj.h"

class MultiClass {
public:
    void Run() {
        std::thread t1(&MultiClass::Calc1, this);
        std::thread t2(&MultiClass::Calc2, this);
        std::thread t3(&MultiClass::Calc3, this);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
private:
    SyncObj obj;
    void Calc1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            obj.waitForCompletionOfT3();
            std::cout << "T1:" << i << std::endl;
            obj.signalCompletionOfT1();
        }           
    }
    void Calc2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            obj.waitForCompletionOfT1();
            std::cout << "T2:" << i << std::endl;
            obj.signalCompletionOfT2();
        }
    }
    void Calc3() {      
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            obj.waitForCompletionOfT2();
            std::cout << "T3:" << i << std::endl;
            obj.signalCompletionOfT3();
        }       
    }
};

SynchObj.h
#include "Header.h"

class SyncObj {
    std::mutex mux;
    std::condition_variable cv;  
    bool completed[3]{ false, false, false };

public:

    /***** Original (t1 & t2) --> t3 *****/
    /*
    void signalCompetionT1T2(int id) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ul(mux);
        completed[id] = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
    void signalCompetionT3() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ul(mux);
        completed[0] = false;
        completed[1] = false;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
    void waitForCompetionT1T2() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mux);             
        cv.wait(ul, [&]() {return completed[0] && completed[1]; });         
    }
    void waitForCompetionT3(int id) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mux);         
        cv.wait(ul, [&]() {return !completed[id]; });           
    }
    */       
    /***********************************/
    
    /*** Unsuccessful attempt at t1 --> t2 --> t3 ***/

    void signalCompletionOfT1() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ul(mux);
        completed[0] = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void signalCompletionOfT2() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ul(mux);
        completed[0] = false;
        completed[1] = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void signalCompletionOfT3() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ul(mux);
        completed[0] = false;
        completed[1] = false;
        completed[2] = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

   void waitForCompletionOfT1() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mux);             
        cv.wait(ul, [&]() {return !completed[2]; });         
    }

    void waitForCompletionOfT2() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mux);             
        cv.wait(ul, [&]() {return !completed[0]; });         
    }

    void waitForCompletionOfT3() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mux);         
        cv.wait(ul, [&]() {return !completed[1]; });           
    }

};

Source.cpp:
#include "Header.h"
#include "MultiClass.h"

int main() {
    MultiClass m;
    m.Run();
    return 0;
}

Possible output #1 (Desired):
T1:1
T1:2
T1:3
T1:4
T1:5
T1:6
T1:7
T1:8
T1:9
T2:0
T2:1
T2:2
T2:3
T2:4
T2:5
T2:6
T2:7
T2:8
T2:9
T3:0
T3:1
T3:2
T3:3
T3:4
T3:5
T3:6
T3:7
T3:8
T3:9

Possible output #2:
0
T2:1
T2:2
T2:3
T2:4
T2:5
T2:6
T2:7
T2:8
T2:9


Usually when I have to perform multithreaded processing on data in a sequential manner I use ring/circular buffers to transmit the data from one thread to another. The buffers allow you to check whether there is data there to be processed or not, thus giving you a synchronization mechanism. Make sure though that the memory accesses are protected to avoid race conditions. Boost seems to have a library that does this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

Sounds a lot like you don't want threading here at all, so why complicate things?

If you think about the tasks you want to schedule, rather than the threads you want to schedule them on, you have three strictly sequential steps and you're asking how to add some synchronization/context-switching cost between them. As asked, it doesn't accomplish anything...

@user4581301 I understand why you're saying this, I'll try to clarify. Maybe I'm missing something. I got 3 functions: the first edits a text file. The second uses system() to run an executable that takes that text file as input. The third reads in data produced by that executable. I tried to simply run 3 code lines one after the other, doesn't work. I assumed that sequential consistency isn't kept (?). I figured I'd run them as threads, which will allow me to dictate execution order.

@barak -- from your description of the task there's no reason for separate threads. Post the code that "doesn't work" and describe what it does. Do this then do that then do something else is inherently single threaded.

"It didn't work" is not useful information. You need to investigate what actually happened. When you understand WHY "it didn't work[,]", you can make progress. Unless you want these three steps executing simultaneously (and probably a couple other esoteric possibilities) threading is the wrong choice. You're trending into Shotgun Debugging, making non-evidentially supported changes to code to solve a problem, and that usually causes more problems than it solves.

Yep, this is a classic "I had N problems, so I added threads, and now I have 1+N! non-deterministic problems". If you don't understand the original issue threads aren't going to help.

Assuming the single threaded example isn't executed in-order is a big leap over the idea that your steps aren't executing correctly.

Firstly, I appreciate your guys' responses. I’d be happy to improve my ways, that’s why I’m here and I thank you for commenting.
Regarding posting the code, it's a several hundred lines of code project, I've been spending some days now trying to give minimal reproducible examples on the site to represent my problem. I guess it reached an end point as of now. I’d rather not link my github, if it’s even adequate.
It’s true, “it doesn’t work” leads no one nowhere. I’m taking in these comments. I’m further examining why my code isn’t working properly, debugging the un-threaded version.

Generally a github link doesn't get you anywhere. Too few people will click on the link to help you in the now, and in the future the link will be blocked by firewalls or what-have-you and rot away and not be useful to future programmers. The MRE is the way to go. Usually making a MRE is easier if the code is modular. If all you need to do to make a MRE is pluck out one function and add a main to call it, you probably won't have too much trouble figuring out what went wrong on your own, but if you do some one here will be able to help out fairly quickly unless that problem is subtle.

You might want to review the way you have organized your include statements. Header.h includes SyncObj.h. SyncObj.h includes Header.h. You will have multiple definitions of Header.h and SyncObj.h in each file at compile time.

Following the comments I debugged deeper.  Found a bug in the open source simulation code that takes the input, runs and gives output. An uninitialized char buffer[2] led to wrong use of sscanf() whenever the second byte is init with a digit. This led to an occasional (~1 in 20) seg fault → a simulation would run but receive SIGSEGV → new output file wasn’t created → the existing output file would be read →what falsely seemed to be a synchronization problem in the reading program. To conclude: I was fast to suspect sequential inconsistency over a subtle bug in a code that I perceived to work.

I leave it to the moderators to decide whether or not this post stays. I think it should

Using Semaphores would a bit more straight forward for this application. The following program outputs your possible output #1:
Compiled with g++ 12.2.1 with command line: g++ -std=c++20 -pthread MultiClass.cpp
Edit: As others have pointed out, doing this single threaded would be better.
MultiClass.cpp
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<iostream>
#include<semaphore>

class MultiClass {
public:
    void Run() {
        std::thread t1(&MultiClass::Calc1, this);
        std::thread t2(&MultiClass::Calc2, this);
        std::thread t3(&MultiClass::Calc3, this);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
private:
    std::binary_semaphore t1{1};
    std::binary_semaphore t2{0};
    std::binary_semaphore t3{0};

    void Calc1() {
        t1.acquire();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            std::cout << "T1:" << i << std::endl;
        }
        t2.release();
    }
    void Calc2() {
        t2.acquire();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            std::cout << "T2:" << i << std::endl;
        }
        t3.release();
    }
    void Calc3() {
        t3.acquire();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            std::cout << "T3:" << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    MultiClass m;
    m.Run();
    return 0;
}



Recommend an edit to make it clear that this is an inferior solution to keeping the stages sequential by not threading at all.

I accept the answer because it’s a working solution to the question I presented. It’s a good solution for a bad question :)  Please see comments above and @user4581301 's comment here.

If you want to run the concurrently and more than once you need to consider how to mimic a Unix / Linux pipe where the output of one process becomes the input of the next process. When the pipe is empty the reading process suspends. When the pipe is full the writing process suspends. In multithreading this is a variation of the producer-consumer model.

This is an extended comment, not an answer.
Your SyncObj class could be simpler. A SyncObj instance has three possible states, which you represent by using three separate bool variables. In electrical engineering, that pattern is known as one-hot encoding. In software engineering (as far as I know) nobody's given it a name because hardly anybody ever uses it.
If an instance has three possible states, the simplest way to represent the state is with an int variable that can be set to 0, 1, or 2 or, with an enum variable that has three possible values. In your case, you always want the states to progress through the same sequence, so the numeric representation probably is more natural. Something like this, for example:
#include "Header.h"

constexpr int NUMPARTICIPANTS=3;

class SyncObj {
    std::mutex mux;
    std::condition_variable cv;  
    int whoseTurn=0;

public:

    void awaitMyTurn(int myID) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ul(mux);
        cv.wait(ul, [&]() {return whoseTurn == myID; });         
    }

    void signalNext() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ul(mux);
        whoseTurn = (whoseTurn + 1) % NUMPARTICIPANTS;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
};

Use it like this:
    void Calc2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            obj.awaitMyTurn(2);
            std::cout << "T2:" << i << std::endl;
            obj.signalNext();
        }
    }

You could fancy it up by making NUMPARTICIPANTS a constructor argument instead of making it a global constant, by throwing an error from awaitMyTurn if the given myID was out-of-bounds, etc.
